# Natbib + BibTeX: How can you show the bibliography in order of appearance AND numbered?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to numerate the references list but having them ordered in order of appearance. I can't find how to do that anywhere.

The code is, more or less, like this

```
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
(...)
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{referencias}
\end{document}
```

The document resulting of that code is close to what I wanted, but the references lists still not numbered. Here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

The thing is, I can set the references to use numbers or Harvard referencing style, but not both.

Is there any way to do this using natbib?

Hope you can understand what am I trying to do here and give me a piece of advice.

Thx a lot!

MWE

.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

First I'm going to cite \citep{DBLP:journals/chb/Junco12}. I also want you to read \citet{Kirschner20101237} and \citep*{Ross2009578}. Don't forget to tell me what do you think about them.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{mwe-ref}
\end{document}
```

.bib

```
@article{DBLP:journals/chb/Junco12,
  author    = {Reynol Junco},
  title     = {Too much face and not enough books: The relationship between
               multiple indices of Facebook use and academic performance},
  journal   = {Computers in Human Behavior},
  volume    = {28},
  number    = {1},
  year      = {2012},
  pages     = {187-198},
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chb.2011.08.026},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}

@article{Ross2009578,
title = "Personality and motivations associated with Facebook use",
journal = "Computers in Human Behavior",
volume = "25",
number = "2",
pages = "578 - 586",
year = "2009",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747563208002355",
author = "Craig Ross and Emily S. Orr and Mia Sisic and Jaime M. Arseneault and Mary G. Simmering and R. Robert Orr"}

@article{Kirschner20101237,
title = "Facebook and academic performance",
journal = "Computers in Human Behavior",
volume = "26",
number = "6",
pages = "1237 - 1245",
year = "2010",
issn = "0747-5632",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747563210000646",
author = "Paul A. Kirschner and Aryn C. Karpinski"}
```

Comment: it works awesome! thx a lot, both of you :)

Comment: Could you comment more on this? I have the same problem and cannot find a solution. So far, my solution has been:
1. Set natbib options to "numbers" and generate the BBL
2. Open the .bbl file and save as a .tex file (with some other name, e.g. fileBib.tex)
3. Use \input{fileBib} at the end of the source file instead of calling the .bib database
4. Re-compiling changing the natbib options to "authoryear". There MUST be an easier way...

Comment: Solution according a [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61877/natbib-sorting-and-citation-order-by-appearance): use `unsrtnat`.

Answer (score 8):

I would drop `authoryear` from `\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but it didn't make the difference. It just replaced the citations in the text with numbers, and numbered the references list. I want to keep the citations as Harvard style (Jones et al., etc)

Comment: works! deleting all temporary files and adding \usepackage{hyperref} - thanks again!

Comment: Great! I am happy to hear

Comment: I honestly don't see how this can work to produce the output requested.

Comment: this does not solve the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Change `\bibliographystyle` to `ieeer` and just keep the option `numbers` when adding `Natbib` package.

Comment: nope: "I couldn't open style file ieeer.bst"

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. My point is to set your style to IEEER. Thus, the preamble should be \usepackage[numbers]{natbib} followed by \bibliographystyle{ieeer}

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: It is ieeetr istead of ieeer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it.

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me with the NeurIPS template, which by default loads `natbib`

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\setcitestyle{square,numbers,comma}
```

works for me