# Harvard style citations with numbered bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have exactly the same question as here:

[Natbib + BibTeX: How can you show the bibliography in order of appearance AND numbered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63855/)

i.e. I want Harvard-style citations in the text but just to add numbers to my list of references.

I've tried using the exact same packages as in the other question,

```
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
(...)
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

However the solution there doesn't solve the problem for me, if I include 'numbers' as an option to natbib, it numbers the references list but the citations in the text just revert to numbers as well, how can I stop this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By including the `numbers` option, you instruct `natbib` to create numeric-style rather than authoryear-style (aka harvard-style) citations. A separate issue: if one doesn't use numbers to signify citations, it's generally meaningless to provide numbers before the entries in the references section. What exactly are readers supposed to take away from seeing each entry prefixed with a number? Check out some academic journals: If they implement an authoryear-style citation system, they (almost!) never prefix the entries in the references section with numbers.

Comment: The package `biblatex` allows different cite style and bibliography style.