# What should I change in a bst file in order to have numbered entries in the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I am using BibTeX with a specific bibliography style (a bst file) which I can't give up.

[This is a link to the .bst file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2mCbPcQ_0DtTEFMU0ZFRXItbGc/edit?usp=sharing). [jon]

I need to edit the .bst file in order to get entry numbering.
This .bst file is an author-year citation style bibliography, which requires to work with the harvard.sty

I tried to compare plain.bst [entries are numbered within square brackets] to alpha.bst [entries appears with the nick from the bib file as a prefix], thinking I will find the required change this way, but with no luck.

With the above bst file my entries looks like (articles, for example):

> ```
> LastName, FirstName, year, Title, Journal ...    volume, pages
> LastName, FirstName, 2ndAuthorFullName, year, Title, Journal, bla bla bla bla bla 
>        bla bla bla bla bla ...
> ```

while I need it to look like this (the numbering is the main issue here) (similar to plain.bst):

> ```
> [1] LastName, FirstName, year, Title, Journal, volume, pages 
>
> [2] LastName, FirstName, 2ndAuthorFullName, year, Title, Journal, bla bla bla bla bla 
>        bla bla bla bla bla ...
> ```

The numbers are only for the list of items and NOT for citation. [Alan Munn]

I can't go to latex or replace my .bst file due to compatibility required.

What can be done?

Comment: What is this mysterious `.bst` file?  It might be helpful if you provided it (or a link to it) along with a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: jon- Thank your for your comment. I've just added a link to the post. I hope it would help.

Comment: Are the numbers used for citations too, or are they just to number the items in the bibliography itself?

Comment: Alan Munn- Thank you for you inquiry. The numbers are only for the list of items and NOT for citation.

Comment: Ok.  This has been asked twice before: [Natbib + BibTeX: How can you show the bibliography in order of appearance AND numbered?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63855) and [Harvard style citations with numbered bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67091)  but unfortunately there are no good answers.  It's a good question.  This is easy to with `biblatex` but non-trivial with `natbib` I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way (code courtesy of Alan Munn).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,etoolbox,lipsum,hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{MyBstFile}

% increase \bibhang to take care of the numbers
\setlength{\bibhang}{2pc}
\makeatletter
% patch \@lbibitem to print the current number before the authors
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {]}
  {][\theNAT@ctr] }
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Chomsky1957,Labov1972} \lipsum[2]

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I added `hyperref` just to be sure that the anchors are correctly set (they are).

[image]

This simple patch has the defect that numbers are not aligned to the last digit. For this a more complicated route should be taken: I decided to write in the aux file the last number, so we can set the widest label at the next run.

Thanks to Alan Munn for providing meaningful references.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}

@article{Barker1998,
    Author = {Chris Barker},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {679-717},
    Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
    Volume = {16},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Berwick1985,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
    Year = {1985}}

@phdthesis{Carlson1977,
    Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
    School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
    Year = {1977}}

@book{Carlson1995,
    Address = {Chicago},
    Editor = {Carlson, Gregory N. and Pelletier, Francis Jeffrey},
    Publisher = {Chicago University Press},
    Title = {The Generic Book},
    Year = {1995}}

@article{Chierchia1998,
    Author = {Gennaro Chierchia},
    Journal = {Natural Language Semantics},
    Pages = {339-405},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds across Languages},
    Volume = {6},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Crain1998,
    Address = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
    Author = {Crain, Stephen and Thornton, Rosalind},
    Publisher = {The MIT Press},
    Title = {Investigations in {U}niversal {G}rammar: A Guide to Experiments on the Acquisition of Syntax and Semantics},
    Year = {1998}}

@article{Dayal2004,
    Author = {Dayal, Veneeta},
    Journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {393--450},
    Title = {Number Marking and (In)Definiteness in Kind Terms},
    Volume = {27},
    Year = {2004}}

@article{Dobrovie-Sorin1998b,
    Author = {Carmen Dobrovie-Sorin and Brenda Laca},
    Journal = {Actes de Langues et Grammaires},
    Pages = {165-179},
    Title = {La g{\'e}nericit{\'e} entre la r{\'e}f{\'e}rence {\`a} l'esp{\`e}ce et la quantification g{\'e}n{\'e}rique},
    Volume = {III},
    Year = {1998}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,etoolbox,lipsum,hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{MyBstFile}

% increase \bibhang to take care of the numbers (adjust at will)
\setlength{\bibhang}{2pc}
\makeatletter
% patch \@lbibitem to print the current number before the authors
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {]}
  {]\bbl@box{\theNAT@ctr} }
  {}{}
% add to the aux file the information about the last number
\apptocmd{\endthebibliography}
  {\if@filesw\write\@mainaux{\string\bbl@lastnumber{\theNAT@ctr}}\fi}
  {}{}
% allocate a length, set to a provisional value
\newlength{\bbl@lastnumberwd}
\setlength\bbl@lastnumberwd{0pt}
% this command will be in the aux file and sets the widest label width
\newcommand\bbl@lastnumber[1]{%
  \settowidth\dimen@{[#1]}%
  \global\bbl@lastnumberwd\dimen@}
% a command to print the number
\newcommand{\bbl@box}[1]{%
  \makebox[\bbl@lastnumberwd][r]{[#1]}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Chomsky1957,Labov1972} \lipsum[2]

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is very nice. However, I use \usepackage{harvard}, and the combination with the above returns lots of error messages like: Command \harvarditem already defined. }   and like: Command \harvardright already defined. \newcommand\harvardright{\NAT@close}

Comment: Just *don't* load `harvard` and keep `natbib`.

Comment: @Different111222 There's no reason for using `harvard`, which is an old (and buggy) package, whereas `natbib` can do the same things and is compatible with your .bst file.