# The most basic biblatex example

Tags: biblatex

I am looking for the most basic example code for using biblatex.

Consider the following bib entries (copied from the answer for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141350/26721) question)

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}
```

and this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
As first example citation here is \cite{Chomsky1957}. 
Here is another example citation \cite{Labov1972}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How should I load biblatex (what should I change in the above code) in order to get numeric citation style that would look like: [1] (a number in a square brackets).

How different (what exactly to change) in order to get author-year style that would look like Labov (1972).

For some reason the list does not print. It is not the main issue here.
However, here is an arbitrary option to list the entries (copied from the same answer above).

What are the additional minimal required commands to print it?

[image]

Answer (score 33):

Bibliography and citation formatting is *complicated*, and that's why the `biblatex` package, which has thought through the issues extremely thoroughly, is also complicated. As end users, we tend to think of simple cases without realizing that making the simple case more general is not always simple.

For this reason, especially if you are a beginner, (and even if you're not) you should try to adapt to some of the standard styles offered by the `biblatex` package itself, or use one of the many excellent user contributed styles that implement most of the major schemes.  This is especially true if you have *any* flexibility in your choice of styles (i.e., you are not bound to a very particular style by a specific journal, for example.)

For a list of available styles see the `biblatex` section of:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)

For author/year citations, the `apa` style for `biblatex` is an excellent implementation of the APA style.

### Citation styles and bibliography styles

There are two main formatting considerations for any citation system: the formatting of the citations themselves in the text, and the formatting of the bibliography items in the bibliography.  The `biblatex` package treats both of these separately, although there are obviously dependencies between the two.  In this answer I will discuss only author/year and numeric schemes, which are common in the natural and social sciences.  Footnote style citations as used in the humanities are quite different, and pose their own set of problems (although `biblatex` is also designed to deal with them.)

### Citation commands

There are three basic citation commands in `biblatex` plus some automatic ones.  All of the citation commands allow two optional arguments: a prenote and a postnote.

1. `\cite`  standard citation
2. `\parencite` standard citation in parentheses
3. `\footcite` like `\cite` but puts the citation in a footnote.

There are many variants of these commands.  See §3.7 of the `biblatex` manual for more details.

Among the more useful special cite commands are:

1. `\textcite` is like `\cite` but puts the label text (like the year in an author/year system) in parentheses.
2. `\autocite`  is designed for (almost) seamlessly transitioning between `\parencite` and `\footcite`, for example, and provides a higher level markup that can be mapped to either command.

### Author/Year Style

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books \autocite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Numeric style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books \autocite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Author/year citations with numeric bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books \autocite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Compiling documents that use `biblatex`

As with other bibliography packages, compiling documents with `biblatex` requires a multi-step process. First you compile your document using your regular TeX engine (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`) and then you run a separate program `biber` which processes the bibliography. For example, if you are compiling any of the  of the  MWEs shown above, using the filename  `test.tex`, then the full compilation command chain would be the following. (Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` or `lualatex` as needed.)

```bash
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```

where `biber test` is short-hand for `biber test.bcf`.

Since most people use IDEs to process their source documents, it's helpful to know how to set up your editor to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`. See this question for details on that.

- [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/2693)

### Do I have to use `biber`? Why can't I use `bibtex`?

Although it's possible with some `biblatex` styles to use `bibtex` to process the bibliography by passing the `[backend=bibtex]` option to the package,  most modern styles depend on the use of `biber` so you should generally *not* use `bibtex` to process documents that use `biblatex`.

Comment: As it does not appear in the code, where did the 'Some famous linguist wrote a couple of books' came from ? BTW, using my system it does not print the list of references at all.

Comment: @Different111222 Fixed.

Comment: How to I change the code so the citation would appear like: Lavov (1972) (I'll deal with the multiple citation later). Also, the citation appear in bold. How do I get rid or that?

Comment: @Different111222 Exchanging `\autocite{Labov1972}` for `\textcite{Labov1972}` should cause the citation to appear in Labov (1972) format.

Comment: @snoringfrog - it changes to Labov1972. How can I put the 1972 in parentheses so it would look like Labov (1972)?

Comment: @alan-munn - I do not see you called `apa` anywhere in the code. Maybe this is the answer - going to something else than `apa`, if it is implemented at all or that it is the default.

Comment: @Different111222 The `apa` style is documented in the `biblatex-apa` documentation. Using it is a bit more complicated than just adding `style=apa`.  Read that documentation if you want APA style.  I highly recommend that package.

Comment: @Different111222 I achieved that output with this code: https://www.writelatex.com/read/bjqcrygcprwh

My major change was specifying `backend=bibtex` as a biblatex argument.

Comment: @SnoringFrog Actually the change that mattered is `\textcite`. Changing the `backend` is not relevant.  I forgot about that in my comment (which I've deleted; thanks for pursuing this.) I don't recommend changing the `backend` to `bibtex` generally. Most of the advanced features of `biblatex` require `biber`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Edited: It appears that this must have been an issue with writelatex.com's implemenation. For some reason, creating the document there requires `backend=bibtex` for the output the asker wanted; I failed to notice the warning thrown when `backend=biber` is used, which is what threw me off. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Maybe you could add a short paragraph about the backend(s) and how to compile such a document, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443969/35864 where the OP wasn't aware of Biber

Comment: @moewe Yes, that probably would have saved me two annoying hours. Just a brief mentioning, that `biber` is actually a standalone program that runs separately from `pdflatex` and is not something that's automagically invoked.
Hence: If `\jobname` is `test`: `pdflatex test.tex; biber test; pdflatex test.tex; pdflatex test.tex`, where `biber test` is short-hand for `biber test.bcf`.