# BibTex style database

Tags: bibtex

There are a couple of great tutorials and tools in the internet for making your customized style for a given journal, for example there is bst generator website, dozen of examples for different journal tastes, and so on.

However, having migrated from Endnote to BibTex and LaTex recently, I was wondering whether there is any convenient bst database for BibTex. For example, [Endnote](http://endnote.com/downloads/styles) provides style database that you only need to know journal name and no further technical details.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A good place to check for this is [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib), but you can generally check the journal's site for one.  It's usually provided for fields where LaTeX is at least semi-common.  You might also want to check out [BibLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141957) for a myriad of improvements over BibTeX.  (*phew—my markdown really suffers when working [in other formats](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/blob/master/stack-mode.org) for so long!*)

Comment: AFAICT, there are various collections of bst files for various subfields such as mathematics, physics, economics, etc. (There are literally thousands, if not tends of thousands, of bst files out there, but no unified guide as to which file does what.) If you have a specific journal in mind, you should check its website to see if there's a bst file that implements the journal's bibliography style requirements.

Comment: CTAN is a good option, however, it does not include all journals. I believe, if we want to answer my question in one sentence it would be "There is no single repository (call it database), similar to Endnote for example". Perhaps a topic for future efforts. If you put your answer below I will accept it as the best one.

Comment: Old lists were kept at http://bst.maururu.net/, but this site is down since 2012. - The old page can be seen at https://web.archive.org/web/20110728032656/http://bst.maururu.net/

Answer (score 5):

It should be more a comment than an answer but I do not have enough rep to comment.

I was managing the bst database at bst.maururu.net but do not have enough time to continue doing so. Of course, I kept a dump of the db, the code of the website and, most importantly, the archive of all styles. To host it, one would need a web server with MySQL and PHP, at their most basic versions.

I would be happy to transfer all that to anyone willing to handle it. Thank you in advance for your help!