# bibtex - citations undefined

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, biber

i am having trouble to get my biblatex to recognize *any* references. here is the output of a minimal examples i found on the web (others behave similar). can you help me? I am using full Miktex installation (all packages pre-installed), and the results below are same for both TexWorks and TexStudio.

Minimal example taken from  [The most basic biblatex example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141957/the-most-basic-biblatex-example)

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some famous linguists wrote a couple of books \autocite{Labov1972,Chomsky1957}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives me

[image]

instead of

[image]

the log says

```
Citation 'Labov1972' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'Chomsky1957' on page 1 undefined
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) spielwiese3(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The .bib file generated by the second minimal example reads (dunno if this is relevant)

```
%% LaTeX2e file `spielwiese3.bib'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `spielwiese3' on 2018/07/31.
%%
 @book{Labov1972,
  Address = {Philadelphia},
  Author = {William Labov},
  Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
  Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
  Year = {1972}}

 @book{Chomsky1957,
  Address = {The Hague},
  Author = {Noam Chomsky},
  Publisher = {Mouton},
  Title = {Syntactic Structures},
  Year = {1957}}
}
```

Running Bibtex results in

```
Prozess gestartet: bibtex.exe "spielwiese3"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: spielwiese3.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file spielwiese3.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file spielwiese3.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file spielwiese3.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

as of writing this cry for help i discover that manually running Biber (not Bibtex!) => PDFLatex returns the desired result:

[image]

could someone explain me what happens?

Comment: You need to run Biber on your file, the log message shows that you ran BibTeX instead. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on running Biber instead of BibTeX with your editor. (See `Please (re)run Biber on the file` in the `.log`, but `This is BibTeX` in the `.blg`)

Comment: Biber is `biblatex`'s replacement for BibTeX. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what BibTeX and Biber do (in general, it is slightly different with `biblatex`, but the analogy still stands) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 has some more about BibTeX vs Biber.

Comment: Did any of the linked questions help you or is there something else you want answered?

Comment: Any news here? Could you solve your problem?

Comment: yes i got the problem solved, both your comments helped. my understanding of biber vs. biblatex is just not good enough to grasp the underlyings. 
basically running biber instead of whatever was the default of my text editor solved it

Comment: Ok, so that would be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864