# Error compiling my bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, preamble

I'm using Gummi {https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/} as my Latex editor.

When I try to compile my .bib file, it returns the following error:

[image]

My .bib file is bibligrafia.bib (generated using BibTex with Zotero): https://file.io/mSNcFvvMs3wQ

My Latex Preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{helvet} % Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % cambiar modo de ver capitulos y secciones
{\large\bfseries\center}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{} % Cambios en Capitulo

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en Sección
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.5em}{3em} % Cambia el espaciamiento del capitulo de 50pt a lo pedido
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3em}{2em} % Cambia el espaciamiento de la sección a 3 espacios en blanco antes y 2 despues.

\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}} % numero de capitulo en listas
\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumi}} % añade lo anterior a sublistas

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.9em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[skip=6pt, indent=1cm, tocskip]{parskip} % configurar espacio entre parrafos y sangría izquierda. tocskip genera el salto entre parrafos en el indice

% paquetes necesarios para citar
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}{}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% ------- PORTADA ------- 

\title{PORTADA}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}


% ------- RESUMEN EJECUTIVO ------- 

\include{1-resumen-ejecutivo.tex}

% ------- CAP 1 INTRODUCCIÓN ------- 

\include{2-introduccion.tex}

% ------- CAP 2 XXXX ------- 

\include{3-capitulo-1.tex}


\end{document}
```

I had to use \addbibresource{bibliografia.bib} for BibLatex package \bibliography{bibliografia.bib}{} for my editor to recognize the bibliography. Don't know if that the best approach, and if that is generating the error.

Without \bibliography{bibliografia.bib}{} I can't detect the .bib file, so it couldn't be compiled.

Edit 1: .log and .blg files: https://file.io/jMzU791OeSoD

Comment: What errors are in the `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: @DaiBowen I will add that to the post, thanks!

Comment: It's always preferred to paste in logs so the question is complete. The `.blg` shows you are running bibtex rather than biber.  [Gummi does not appear to offer UI-level biber support](https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/issues/6), your options appear to be [latexmk or arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207464/106162), or run biber manually on the command line.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks for the help, didn't knew that biber wasn't supported. I would try to look for another Latex Editor. Any recommendation for a Light one?

Comment: @JJP Take a look at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/106162). TeXworks is probably the lightest and most straightforward tex-specific editor and you likely already have it installed, texmaker/texstudio/vs code are a bit heftier but may be worth looking at.