# Start elsarticle-harv.bst numbering from 1

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, bst

I'm using elsarticle-harv.bst for my thesis bibliography and, along with this, I am numbering the references based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141350/149294 as follows:

```
% increase \bibhang to take care of the numbers (adjust at will)
\setlength{\bibhang}{2pc}
\makeatletter
% patch \@lbibitem to print the current number before the authors
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {]}
  {]\bbl@box{\theNAT@ctr} }
  {}{}
% add to the aux file the information about the last number
\apptocmd{\endthebibliography}
  {\if@filesw\write\@mainaux{\string\bbl@lastnumber{\theNAT@ctr}}\fi}
  {}{}
% allocate a length, set to a provisional value
\newlength{\bbl@lastnumberwd}
\setlength\bbl@lastnumberwd{0pt}
% this command will be in the aux file and sets the widest label width
\newcommand\bbl@lastnumber[1]{
  \settowidth\dimen@{[#1]}
  \global\bbl@lastnumberwd\dimen@}
% a command to print the number
\newcommand{\bbl@box}[1]{
  \makebox[\bbl@lastnumberwd][r]{[#1]}
}
\makeatother
```

However, my numbering begins from 0 instead of 1. How may I modify the code so as to make it start from 1?

[image: References up to the 7th one]

This is the `cls` file I am using:

```
% iitbthesis.cls
% LaTeX Style file for the Indian Institute of Bombay Thesis Format
%
% Many commands copied from withesis.cls from 
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/withesis/
%
%=============================================================================
% Licensed under the Perl Artistic License.
% see: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/licenses.artistic.html
% for more info...
%=============================================================================
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{iitbthesis}[2007/06/25 IIT Bombay Thesis Format]
\typeout{Document Class `iitbthesis' v0.95beta <18 Sept 07>}


%=============================================================================
% TBD: We need options to switch between Annual Progress Report,
%      Presynopsis, Synopsis and final thesis, and between different
%      types of reports. 
%=============================================================================
%\DeclareOption{aps}{}
%\DeclareOption{presynopsis}{}
%\DeclareOption{synopsis}{}
%\DeclareOption{thesis}{}
%\DeclareOption{dissertation}{}
%\DeclareOption{project}{}

%=============================================================================
% Pass the options to report class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

% Defaults ...
\ProcessOptions

%=============================================================================
% a4paper: thesis must be printed on a4 size paper. 
% 12pt:    font size must be 12 pt
%
% As iitbthesis class is a simple extension of report class, we simply
% pass default options to report class.
% =============================================================================
\PassOptionsToClass{12pt,a4paper}{report}
\LoadClass{report}

% who is advisor?
\def\@advisorname{None}
\newcommand{\setguide}[1]{\def\@advisorname{#1}}

% and coadvisor? (initialized to empty)
\global\let\@coadvisorname\@empty
\newcommand{\setcoguide}[1]{\def\@coadvisorname{#1}}
\let\coguide\setcoguide %
\newcommand{\show@coguide}{\@coadvisorname}

% and exadvisor? (initialized to empty)
\global\let\@exadvisorname\@empty
\newcommand{\setexguide}[1]{\def\@exadvisorname{#1}}
\let\exguide\setexguide %
\newcommand{\show@exguide}{\@exadvisorname}

%=============================================================================
% TITLE PAGE
%   - define \title{} \author{} \date{}
%   - The default degree is ``Unknown Degree''
%     Degree can be changed using the command \iitbdegree{}
%   - The default department is ``Unknown Department''
%     The department can be changed using the command \department{}
%   - The default document type is ``A preliminary report''
%     The document type can be changed using the command \reporttype{}
%     There are some short-cuts for \reporttype{}:
%      * for a PhD thesis, specify \thesis
%      * for a M.Tech./M.Phil./M.Des./M.S. dissertation, specify \dissertation
%      * for a DIIT/B.Tech./M.Sc.project report, specify \project
%      * for a preliminary report, specify \prelim
%   - once the above are defined, use \maketitle to generate the titlepage
%=============================================================================
\newcommand\@thesistitlemedskip{0.25in}
\newcommand\@thesistitlebigskip{0.6in}
\newcommand{\rollnum}[1]{\gdef\@rollnum{#1}}
\newcommand{\iitbdegree}[1]{\gdef\@iitbdegree{#1}}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\newcommand{\reporttype}[1]{\gdef\@doctype{#1}}
\newcommand{\approvaltype}[1]{\gdef\@approvaltype{#1}}

\newcommand{\thesis}{\reporttype{}\approvaltype{Thesis}}
\newcommand{\dissertation}{\reporttype{dissertation}\approvaltype{Dissertation}}
\newcommand{\project}{\reporttype{project report}\approvaltype{Report}}
\newcommand{\prelim}{\reporttype{preliminary report}\approvaltype{Report}}

\gdef\@rollnum{Unknown 00000000}    % Default is Unknown 00000000
\gdef\@iitbdegree{Unknown Degree}    % Default is Unknown Degree
\gdef\@doctype{preliminary report}  % Default is a preliminary report
\gdef\@department{(Unknown Department)} % Default is Unknown

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- The thesis office doesn't like thanks on title page.  Put it in
% -- the acknowledgments.  This is here so you don't have to change
% -- your titlepage when converting from report style. -> from Purdue, but I
%        left it here since it seems compatible with UW-Madison, Eric -
%    Amey - I also left it here as IITB does not say anything about it.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \def\thanks##1{\typeout{Warning: `thanks' deleted from thesis titlepage.}}
    \let\footnotesize\small \let\footnoterule\relax \setcounter{page}{1}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{center}
      \mbox{}\\
      {\bf\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\LARGE\@title}} \\[\@thesistitlebigskip]
      {\large  \@doctype\ Submitted in partial fulfillment of  the requirements} \\
      {\large  of the degree of}\\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large \@iitbdegree} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large by} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large \bf \@author} \\
      {\large \bf (Roll No. \@rollnum)} \\[\@thesistitlebigskip]
      {\large Supervisor: }  \\
      {\large \bf \@advisorname} \\
      \ifx\@coadvisorname\@empty
         \ifx\@exadvisorname\@empty
             \mbox{}\\[\@thesistitlebigskip]
     \else
         {\large and } \\
         {\large \bf \@exadvisorname} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
     \fi %
      \else
          \ifx\@exadvisorname\@empty
          {\large  } \\
          {\large \bf \@coadvisorname} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      \else
          {\large \bf \@coadvisorname} \\%[\@thesistitlemedskip]
          {\large and } \\
          {\large \bf \@exadvisorname} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      \fi %
      \fi %
      \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{iitblogo.png} \\[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large \uppercase{\@department}} \\%[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large INDIAN INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY BOMBAY}\\%[\@thesistitlemedskip]
      {\large \@date}
    \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \setcounter{page}{1} %title page is NOT counted
}

%=============================================================================
% DEDICATION
%=============================================================================
% The dedication environment must do the following:
% - start a new page
% - center the text vertically
% - include the text in a center environment
%=============================================================================
\def\dedication{
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}    % No page number
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  % \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \chapter*{}            % Required for \vfill to work
  \thispagestyle{empty}    % No page number
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}}
\def\enddedication{\end{center}\par\vfil\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% APPROVAL SHEET
% - start a new page. page 
% - center the text vertically
%=============================================================================
\newcommand\@thesisapprovalmedskip{0.2in}
\newcommand\@thesisapprovalbigskip{0.5in}
\newcommand{\makeapproval}{
  %\setcounter{page}{2}
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    {\LARGE \bf \@approvaltype\ Approval}\\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]
    {\large The \@doctype\ entitled}\\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]
    {\bf\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\LARGE\@title}}\\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]
    {\large by}\\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]
    {\Large \bf \@author }\\
    {\Large (Roll No. \@rollnum)}\\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]
    {\large is approved for the degree of} \\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]
    {\large \@iitbdegree } \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]
    \ifx\@coadvisorname\@empty
    \ifx\@exadvisorname\@empty % no co-advisor/external advisor
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                &\rule{10mm}{0pt}& \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Examiner}              && {\Large Examiner} \\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]\\
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                && \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Supervisor}                 && {\Large Chairman} \\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]\\
      {\Large Date:} \rule{4cm}{1sp} && \\ && \\
      {\Large Place:} \rule{4cm}{1sp}&&
    \end{tabular}
    \else % only external advisor
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                & \rule{10mm}{0pt} & \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Examiner}              && {\Large Examiner} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                && \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Guide}                 && {\Large External Guide} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\rule{6cm}{1sp}} \\
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large Chairman} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]
      {\Large Date:} \rule{4cm}{1sp} && \\ && \\
      {\Large Place:} \rule{4cm}{1sp}&&
    \end{tabular}
    \fi %
    \else % coadvisor
    \ifx\@exadvisorname\@empty % but no external advisor 
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                &\rule{10mm}{0pt}& \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Examiner}              && {\Large Examiner} \\[\@thesisapprovalmedskip]\\
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                && \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Guide}                 && {\Large Co Guide} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\rule{6cm}{1sp}} \\
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large Chairman} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]
      {\Large Date:} \rule{4cm}{1sp} && \\ && \\
      {\Large Place:} \rule{4cm}{1sp}&&
    \end{tabular}
    \else % both co-advisor and external advisor
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                & \rule{10mm}{0pt} & \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Examiner}              && {\Large Examiner} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                && \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Guide}                 && {\Large External Guide} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      \rule{6cm}{1sp}                && \rule{6cm}{1sp} \\
      {\Large Co Guide}              && {\Large Chairman} \\[\@thesisapprovalbigskip]\\
      {\Large Date:} \rule{4cm}{1sp} && \\ && \\
      {\Large Place:} \rule{4cm}{1sp}&&
    \end{tabular}
    \fi %exadvisor empty
    \fi %coadvisor empty
     
%change ends    

  \end{center}
  \let\thanks\relax
  \let\maketitle\relax \let\iitbdegree\relax \let\project\relax \let\prelim\relax
  \let\department\relax
  \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@iitbdegree{}\gdef\@doctype{}
  \gdef\@department{}
}

%=============================================================================
% CERTIFICATE OF COURSE WORK
%=============================================================================
% joining date is required for certificate of course work
\newcommand{\joiningdate}[1]{\gdef\@joindate{#1}}
\gdef\@joindate{``Unknown''}
%   - define counters for course numbers & credits, initialize to 0
\newcounter{@course}\setcounter{@course}{0}
\newcounter{@credits}\setcounter{@credits}{0}

%   - command to add a course. it accepts 3 arguments:
%     Course ID, Course Name, and Course Credits.
\newcommand{\addcourse}[3]{%
  \addtocounter{@course}{1}
  \the@course & #1 & #2 & #3
  \addtocounter{@credits}{#3} \\\hline}
\newcommand{\addppcourse}[3]{%
  \addtocounter{@course}{1}
  \the@course & #1 & #2 & #3
  \\\hline}

%  - finally the environment to print course list in tabular form
\newenvironment{coursecertificate}{
  \newpage
  %\setcounter{page}{0}
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    {\Large INDIAN INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY BOMBAY, INDIA}\\
    \vspace{.3in}
    {\Large \bf CERTIFICATE OF COURSE WORK}\\
    \vspace{.5in}
  \end{center}
  {\large This is to certify that {\bf \@author} (Roll No. \@rollnum)
    was admitted to the candidacy of Ph.D. degree on \@joindate,
    after successfully completing all the courses required for the
    Ph.D. programme. The details of the course work done are given
    below.}\\
  \vspace{.3in}\\
  \begin{tabular}{|r|l|p{10cm}|r|}
    \hline
    {\bf S.No} & {\bf Course Code} & {\bf Course Name} & {\bf Credits}\\
    \hline\hline}% Begining of environment
  {
    \hline
    & & {\bf Total Credits} & {\bf \the@credits} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  
  \vfill
  {\large 
  \begin{tabular}{lp{2.2in}r}
    IIT Bombay &&\\
    Date: & &Dy. Registrar (Academic)
  \end{tabular}} % End of Course Certificate
}


%=============================================================================
% ABSTRACT
%=============================================================================
% The abstract should begin with two single-spaced lines describing
% the author and title in a standard format.  After these lines comes
% the standard abstract.
%=============================================================================
\def\abstract{
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \relax\markboth{ABSTRACT}{ABSTRACT}}
\def\endabstract{\par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% COPYRIGHTPAGE
% The copyright must do the following:
% - start a new page with no number
% - place the copyright text centered at the bottom.
%=============================================================================
\def\copyrightpage{
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}    % No page number
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  % \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \chapter*{}            % Required for \vfill to work
  \begin{center}
   \vfill
   \copyright\ Copyright by \@author\ \@date\\
   All Rights Reserved
  \end{center}}


%=============================================================================
% GLOSSARY
%=============================================================================
% The glossary environment must do the following:
% - produce the table of contents entry for the glossary
% - start a new page with GLOSSARY centered two inches from the top
%=============================================================================
\def\glossary{
  \chapter*{Glossary}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}}
\def\endglossary{\par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% NOMENCLATURE
%=============================================================================
% The nomenclature environment must do the following:
% - produce the table of contents entry for the nomenclature section
% - start a new page with NOMENCLATURE centered two inches from the top
%=============================================================================
\def\nomenclature{ 
  \chapter*{Nomenclature}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}}
\def\endnomenclature{\par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% LIST OF SYMBOLS
%=============================================================================
% The list of symbols environment must do the following:
% - produce the table of contents entry for the list of symbols section
% - start a new page with LIST OF SYMBOLS centered two inches from the top
%=============================================================================
\def\listofsymbols{
  \chapter*{List of Symbols}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}}
\def\endlistofsymbols{\par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% VITA
%=============================================================================
% The vita environment must do the following:
% - produce a separator page with the word vita centered
% - produce the table of contents entry for the vita
% - start a new page with VITA centered two inches from the top
%=============================================================================
\def\vita{
  \chapter*{Vita}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vita}}
\def\endvita{\par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% ACKNOWLEDGMENTS
%=============================================================================
% The acknowledgments environment must do the following:
% - start a new page with ACKNOWLEDGMENTS centered two inches from the top
%=============================================================================
\def\acknowledgments{
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \doublespace}
\def\endacknowledgments{%
  \vskip 5cm
  \noindent{\large Date: \rule{4cm}{1sp}\hfill\@author\rule{1cm}{0pt}}
  \par\newpage}

%=============================================================================
% \@makecaption{NUMBER}{TEXT} : Macro to make a figure or table caption.
%      NUMBER : Figure or table number--e.g., 'Figure 3.2'
%      TEXT   : The caption text.
%  Macro should be called inside a \parbox of right width, with \normalsize.
%=============================================================================
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \singlespace#1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

%=============================================================================
% LIST OF FIGURES; LIST OF TABLES
%  These macros from report.cls have been modified to add entry in the
%  Contents table
%=============================================================================
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
%=============================================================================
% These commands can be used in the thesis to switch between single
% and double spacing.  This is needed, for instance, in the abstract.
%=============================================================================
\newcommand{\oneskip}{1.0}
\newcommand{\twoskip}{1.5}
\newcommand{\singlespace}
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\oneskip}\Large\normalsize}
\newcommand{\doublespace}
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\twoskip}\Large\normalsize}

%=============================================================================
% Finally set the various lengths/margins as required by IITB format
% Check out LaTeX Companion for more details.
%=============================================================================
% Paper height & width (A4 paper) - set by a4paper option to report
%\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
%\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
% total text area: height & width
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}

\setlength{\headheight}{3mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{12mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{15mm}
% left side empty space on odd- & even-numbered pages
\if@twoside
  \typeout{Two side is true}
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30mm}  % for two side printing
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{20mm}
\else
  \typeout{Two side is false}
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30mm}  % for one side printing
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{30mm} % odd side margin = even side margin
\fi
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in} % already accounted for in the margins
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in} % already accounted for in the margins
% line, paragraphs indent & spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex} % indentation 5 characters approx.

\doublespace

%=============================================================================
% END FILE
%=============================================================================

\newcommand\quotationpage{
\begin{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
%\hspace*{\hfill}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{Figure_General/quote.png}
\end{figure}
%\hspace*{\hfill}






\end{titlepage}
}
```

I have a separate file named `mybibfile.bib` in a folder named `references` which starts off as:

```
BOOKS

@book{ref06,
  doi        = {10.1017/CBO9780511815652},
  year       = {1997},
  place      = {Cambridge},
  title      = {Spacecraft Dynamics and Control: A Practical Engineering Approach},
  author     = {Sidi, Marcel J.},
  series     = {Cambridge Aerospace Series},
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press},
  collection = {Cambridge Aerospace Series},
}

@book{ref08,
  doi        = {10.1016/C2011-0-69685-1},
  year       = {2005},
  place      = {Amsterdam},
  title      = {Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students},
  author     = {Curtis, Howard D.},
  series     = {Elsevier Butterworth Heinemann},
  publisher  = {Elsevier Butterworth Heinemann},
  collection = {Elsevier Butterworth Heinemann},
}

@book{ref18,
  year       = {2004},
  place      = {Bristol, Philadelphia},
  title      = {Orbital Motion},
  author     = {Roy, A.E.},
  series     = {CRC Press},
  publisher  = {CRC Press},
  collection = {CRC Press},
}

@book{ref37,
  doi        = {10.1007/b97612},
  year       = {2003},
  place      = {New York},
  title      = {The Design and Construction of Large Optical Telescopes},
  author     = {Bely, Pierre},
  series     = {Springer-Verlag},
  publisher  = {Springer-Verlag},
  collection = {Springer-Verlag},
}

@book{ref53,
  year       = {2009},
  title      = {Spacecraft Formation Flying: Dynamics, Control and Navigation},
  author     = {Alfriend, Kyle and Vadali, Srinivas and Gurfil, Pini and How, Jonathan and Breger, Louis},
  series     = {Butterworth-Heinemann},
  publisher  = {Butterworth-Heinemann},
  collection = {Butterworth-Heinemann},
}

@book{ref56,
  year       = {2003},
  title      = {Automated Rendezvous and Docking of Spacecraft},
  author     = {Fehse, Wigbert},
  series     = {Cambridge University Press},
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press},
  collection = {Cambridge University Press},
  doi        = {10.1017/CBO9780511543388},
}
```

I don't mind that the bibliography is in alphabetical order or anything else. My only two requirements are that the citings should be in the form `A et al. (YYYY)` which it is as of now and that the numbering should begin from 1.

I have tried out `elsarticle-num.bst` as suggested by @Mico and, although the numbering issue is solved, the citings are now in numerals and not in the above form.
I have also tried bringing the `elsarticle-harv.bst` file to the main directory and renaming it as `MyBstFile.bst` but the numbering is still from 0.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of idle curiosity: Have you tried employing the `elsarticle-num ` bibliography style, which provides numeric-style citation call-outs "out of the box"?

Comment: Perhaps the numbering is set to start from 0 by your thesis class? Can you provide a minimal example that replicates the behaviour on our end?

Comment: @Werner I've updated the question with the cls file. Please let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the tip. I'm new to bibliography styles, so I didn't know there was something like that. I'll try that out

Comment: @Mico I tried that out and the numbering worked out well (starting from 1 and not 0). However, the text cites references by number and not by name. Is there any way to rectify that?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu - Thanks for clarifying your formatting objectives. I had been under the erroneous impression that since you wanted to number the bibliographic entries, you also intended to create numeric-style ctation call-outs.

Comment: @Aaron John Sabu Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it doesn't include enough detail to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Werner I don't understand what's missing.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: The current accepted answer just points to "everything working as expected" with the information provided. And [you commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591868/start-elsarticle-harv-bst-numbering-from-1?noredirect=1#comment1484831_591881) that you had an *outdated* [`natbib`](//ctan.org/pkg/natbib). While using an updated version of `natbib` is the solution, even using `natbib` wasn't included in your question. So, as the question stands, it's not possible to replicate the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by an old/modified version of a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `.bib` file from the link you  provided. Put the `elsarticle-harv.bst` in the same directory of the main file and renamed it as  `MyBstFile.bst`.

After the several required runs, everything seems fine.

References are numbered correctly without the need to modify the style. You didn't provide a full MWE so I don't know if I'm missing something.

**UPDATE**

Using the class `iitbthesis.cls` and the same procedure

[image: up]

Cites in de document

[image: out]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Labov1972,
        Address = {Philadelphia},
        Author = {William Labov},
        Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
        Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
        Year = {1972}}
    
    @book{Chomsky1957,
        Address = {The Hague},
        Author = {Noam Chomsky},
        Publisher = {Mouton},
        Title = {Syntactic Structures},
        Year = {1957}}
    
    @article{Barker1998,
        Author = {Chris Barker},
        Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
        Pages = {679-717},
        Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
        Volume = {16},
        Year = {1998}}
    
    @book{Berwick1985,
        Address = {Cambridge, MA},
        Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
        Publisher = {MIT Press},
        Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
        Year = {1985}}
    
    @phdthesis{Carlson1977,
        Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
        School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
        Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
        Year = {1977}}
    
    @book{Carlson1995,
        Address = {Chicago},
        Editor = {Carlson, Gregory N. and Pelletier, Francis Jeffrey},
        Publisher = {Chicago University Press},
        Title = {The Generic Book},
        Year = {1995}}
    
    @article{Chierchia1998,
        Author = {Gennaro Chierchia},
        Journal = {Natural Language Semantics},
        Pages = {339-405},
        Title = {Reference to Kinds across Languages},
        Volume = {6},
        Year = {1998}}
    
    @book{Crain1998,
        Address = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
        Author = {Crain, Stephen and Thornton, Rosalind},
        Publisher = {The MIT Press},
        Title = {Investigations in {U}niversal {G}rammar: A Guide to Experiments on the Acquisition of Syntax and Semantics},
        Year = {1998}}
    
    @article{Dayal2004,
        Author = {Dayal, Veneeta},
        Journal = {Linguistics and Philosophy},
        Number = {4},
        Pages = {393--450},
        Title = {Number Marking and (In)Definiteness in Kind Terms},
        Volume = {27},
        Year = {2004}}
    
    @article{Dobrovie-Sorin1998b,
        Author = {Carmen Dobrovie-Sorin and Brenda Laca},
        Journal = {Actes de Langues et Grammaires},
        Pages = {165-179},
        Title = {La g{\'e}nericit{\'e} entre la r{\'e}f{\'e}rence {\`a} l'esp{\`e}ce et la quantification g{\'e}n{\'e}rique},
        Volume = {III},
        Year = {1998}}
\end{filecontents}  

\documentclass{iitbthesis} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed from report

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{natbib} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added

\usepackage{etoolbox}
    
\bibliographystyle{MyBstFile} % elsarticle-harv.bst renamed 

%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141003/what-should-i-change-in-a-bst-file-in-order-to-have-numbered-entries-in-the-bibl/141350#141350
% increase \bibhang to take care of the numbers (adjust at will)
\setlength{\bibhang}{2pc}
\makeatletter
% patch \@lbibitem to print the current number before the authors
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
{]}
{]\bbl@box{\theNAT@ctr} }
{}{}
% add to the aux file the information about the last number
\apptocmd{\endthebibliography}
{\if@filesw\write\@mainaux{\string\bbl@lastnumber{\theNAT@ctr}}\fi}
{}{}
% allocate a length, set to a provisional value
\newlength{\bbl@lastnumberwd}
\setlength\bbl@lastnumberwd{0pt}
% this command will be in the aux file and sets the widest label width
\newcommand\bbl@lastnumber[1]{%
    \settowidth\dimen@{[#1]}%
    \global\bbl@lastnumberwd\dimen@}
% a command to print the number
\newcommand{\bbl@box}[1]{%
    \makebox[\bbl@lastnumberwd][r]{[#1]}%
}
\makeatother
%% ***********************************************************************

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}
    
As  \cite{Chomsky1957,Labov1972},

\citet{Chomsky1957}

\citep{Chomsky1957}

\citep[see][]{Chomsky1957}

\citet*{Chomsky1957}
    
\citet[chap.~2]{Chomsky1957}

\citealt{Chomsky1957}

\citealp{Chomsky1957}
    
\citenum{Chomsky1957}   
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

Repeating the same procedure with `apa.bst` the output is

[image: ap]

Comment: Hi Simon, I have updated the question. I tried bringing it to the main directory and renaming it but unfortunately it hasn't helped.

Comment: @Aaron John Sabu Please see my updated answer. Use a new clean directory with  my example.

Comment: Ah! I figured it out. You had explicitly called `natbib`, so I rechecked my code. There was an outdated version of `natbib` that was explicitly defined as a file. I removed the file and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron John Sabu Thank you for your feedback!