# Citation with only a number between bracket

Tags: citing, natbib

I cannot figure out how to make my citations appear with a simple number between brackets, like `[1]`.
I obtain: `"author et al. [year]"`
I use the documentclass `book` with `natbib`-package.

Edit1:
I tried `\citet{key}` instead of `\cite{}`, it has no effect.

Comment: See section 3.1 of the [natbib documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib?lang=en) (or `texdoc natbib` on your system).  If you are still stuck after that, just update your question and we will try and help.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: this should also answer your questions in addition to @AndrewSwann's comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63855/natbib-bibtex-how-can-you-show-the-bibliography-in-order-of-appearance-and-nu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't specified which bibliography style you use. Assuming it's a style that can generate both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs -- *some* bibliography styles can generate only the latter type... -- you should load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. Alternatively, issue the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{numbers}
```

*after* loading the `natbib` package.

Comment: How do you go about it when you only want to do it for a specific citation and not all of them?

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
```

or

Look at the link:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_natbib

It is explained very clearly over there!!

Comment: Instead of posting a link, could you describe the key points in this answer?