# make order of bibliographic entries same as order of citation call-outs within body of document

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am writing an article. I would like the references to appear in the order in which they occur in the paper. I am using natbib, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you should probably use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. Simply issue the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` somewhere in the document and then run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the changes.

Comment: relevant: [Natbib sorting and citation order by appearance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61877/579)