# Changing the order of references using the ACM-Reference-Format bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, acmart

I am preparing a manuscript of a paper using documentclass **acmart**. I am using bibliographystyle **ACM-Reference-Format**. But my references are neither printed in the order of citation nor in alphabetical order. Can somebody please guide me to solve this problem. I would like to print the references in the order of citation. 
Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to let others provide a diagnosis of the problem, let alone suggest a cure. Please provide a minimal compilable example that generates the problem you wish to fix. The example code should contain three (or maybe more) bibliographic entries and corresponding `\cite` commands.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: If the document you are writing should be published with ACM it is most likely wise to not make any changes to the ACM bibliography style without consulting with the editors.
The document might not be accepted if a modified template is used.

That being said, if you don't intend to publish with ACM:

The `acmart` documentclass uses the [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package for reference management by default, which uses the `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` file for styling.
You might want to use an alternative style that has your desired properties, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61877/natbib-sorting-and-citation-order-by-appearance#61889).

Furthermore, you might want to use the package [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) instead for reference management, which does not require changing the `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` file.
You can use biblatex with acmart by passing the option `natbib=false` to `\documentclass`

```
\documentclass[natbib=false]{acmart}
```

Comment: Please state how this posting addresses the OP's query, which was (to my reading) about trying to get a certain bibliography style to perform sorting correctly.

Comment: adding `natbib=false` does not solve the sorting problem. Instead, it shows something like `[Popović(2017)] Maja Popović. 2017. chrF++: words helping character n‑grams. In Proceedings of the Second Conference on Machine Translation.
Association for Computational Linguistics, Copenhagen, Denmark, 612–618. https://doi.org/10.18653/v1/W17‑4770`. The numbering is missing, and it is still not in alphabetical order.