# How is it possible that references are not in the correct order if I put them in a figure caption in LyX?

Tags: bibtex, floats, lyx, captions, back-referencing

I'm using LyX and I added a reference to a figure caption. Now this reference is the number [1] in the reference list even if it appears later than many others. It looks like the float captions have a higher priority in counting references' appearance.
I added many things to my preamble but even if I delete those lines in the preamble the problem stays.
I'm using a customized bibtex style, but in a brand new article it works in the proper way. 
Where could the problem stay?

Comment: There could be some sort-order specified (perhaps alphabetical)? What mechanism do you use to process your citations in LyX?

Comment: It's possible if you have a list of figures at least.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/latex-bibtex-not-arranging-citations-by-order-of-appearance

Answer (score 1):

A fancy way for avoiding this problem is to add a short title to the figure (without the citation). This is possible in LyX without adding any additional package to the preamble.