# References are not appearing in the correct order

Tags: citing, thesis

I'm writing my thesis with the following format: My problem is that the references are not appearing in the correct, I'm having my first ref to be cited as 11 instead of 1! Although in the bibliography at the end it is shown in the correct order..

```
\documentclass[letter, onecolumn, 12pt] {report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}

\newenvironment{proof}{{\bf Proof.}}{\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}}

\newenvironment{remark}{\begin{remarka}\rm}{\end{remarka}}

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\input{head.tex}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\maketitlepage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setlength{\parskip}{.25cm}
```

EVERYTHING GOES HERE THE ABSTRACT AND CHAPTERS

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{JETCAS_2014_v2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid it's not easy to say why your citation callouts might be out of (numeric) sequence since your code provides no `\cite` commands. Moreover, there seems to be a file `head.tex` about whose contents no information is available.

Comment: head.tex contains the supervisors' names and date only

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem you describe -- citation callouts not being numbered in the order they occur in the document -- using just the code you've provided. Please provide a real [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you say you're encountering. Please attempt to make the example code *minimal*, in the sense that you don't load all kinds of packages that are not relevant for the problem at hand. If any `\cite` commands occur inside `\caption` or `\section`-type commands, please be sure to mention this fact.

Comment: Yes, I have so many references inside captions, tables and of course sections and chapters. The list of figures and tables references start from 1 and ends at 10 and then the first reference in the paragraph starts by 11. So I tried removing the \listoffigures and \listoftables and then the ref appeared in the correct order!

Comment: But now how can I add both list of figures and list of tables without disturbing the order of the reference?? Any suggestions?

Comment: See if any of the suggestions in [LaTeX/BibTex not arranging citations by order of appearance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61875) help.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! I just added notoccite package and it worked..