# starting the references from main text, not from the list

Tags: bibliographies

I want my references to be sorted in the order of presence in the text. I use unsrt.bst and it works well. The only problem is that before the main text starts, I have a list of figures and in the caption of some figures, I have citation. So the unsrt.bst start numbering the references from list of figures. It means that the first reference is in the list, not the main text.

Is there any way for unsrt.bst to ignore citation in list and start its numbering from the main text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/latex-bibtex-not-arranging-citations-by-order-of-appearance Method 1 in the most voted answer (that is, `\usepackage{notoccite}`) seems the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved by the package [`notoccite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/notoccite).

Here the introduction of the package:

> If you have `\cite` com­mands in `\sec­tion`-like com­mands, or in
>   `\cap­tion`, the ci­ta­tion will also ap­pear in the ta­ble of
>   con­tents, or list of what­ever. If you are also us­ing an un­srt-like
>   bib­li­og­ra­phy style, these ci­ta­tions will come at the very start
>   of the bib­li­og­ra­phy, which is con­fus­ing. This pack­age
>   sup­presses the ef­fect.