# reference in latex in not sequentially

Tags: bibliographies, cite-package

In spite of the suggested solutions to fix the problem in arranging the references based on the citations, still couldn't fix it and I don't know why!

The solutions that I have tried are:

1. Remove all of the `AUX` and `BBL` files and re-run the file.
2. Arranging the references based on the citations

I went through several links talk about similar issues, and follow the suggested solutions but unfortunately no solution has been reached so far.

The code that I have:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Progress.tex
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
\documentclass{ecsthesis}    % Use the progress Style
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, boldline} %
\usepackage{cellspace}
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}   % Set to false for black/white printing
\input{Definitions}            % Include your abbreviations
\usepackage[sort]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{nomencl} % for abbrevations 

\usepackage{grffile} 

\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title      {Ssss}
\authors    {\texorpdfstring
     {\href{mailto:aak}{aaa}}
     {aa a. a}
    }

\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}



\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

aaa

\end{abstract}




\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\listofsymbols{ll}{$HVDC$ & High Voltage Direct Current\\
$DC$ &  Direct Current\\
$AC$ &  Alternating Current\\
}
\acknowledgements{aaa }
%\dedicatory{To \dots}
\mainmatter
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\include{Introduction}
\include{PolymericAgeingModels}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Thesis_references}
\end{document} 
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use `\cite{}` for citation.

---

Update on Friday 25/09/2015 at 17:25:
I found the solution by adding:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{notoccite}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to use `biblatex`. So I re-tagged your question. You might be able to receive help quicker, if you make your MWE fully minimal and make sure we can compile it without having to fake files such as `Thesis_references`. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) It can also help us of you explicitly link to the solutions you have already tried.

Comment: I found the solution is by adding \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    \usepackage{notoccite}

Comment: @moewe Do we have a dupe around? Without seeing the solution, i wouldn't  even know what this question is about. Maybe unclear?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not exactly sure either, but `notoccite` suggests https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61869/35864

Comment: @moewe I voted for dupe.