# Ordering citations by appearance

Tags: bibtex, natbib, texmaker, sorting

I'm new to Latex and I'm writing a report. My first citation is in an image. I got the first citation to be [1] but the second one by appearance comes as [5]. I have tried ieeetr style and that doesn't work either.

````
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  % unicode
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %Adds "References" to the table of contents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}```

Can someone please help me?
````

Comment: Do any `\cite` instructions occur in the arguments of `\caption` statements?

Comment: As errors? No. It even appears in the list of figures.

Comment: Does running `\usepackage{notoccite}` and recompiling twice help?

Comment: See also [LaTeX/BibTex not arranging citations by order of appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61869/5001.)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was solved by a comment.