# Preserving Original Reference Numbers in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I have included a citation to a research paper (let us assume that it is reference number 100 in the bibliography) in the one-line caption of a figure located near the end of my document. My references are in BibTeX format, and when I create a list of figures at the beginning of the document, the reference number of that citation becomes 1 in the bibliography list. I would like to maintain the original reference number (100) in the bibliography list. How can I achieve this while using a BibTeX file for my references?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: List of figures and friends can mess with "unsorted" styles that arrange bib entries by citation order. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61869/35864 for hints.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I have found this - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61875/149108.
It works for me. Thank you.