# Bibligraphy ordering - ignore entry

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am using BibTeX with `natbib`. My style file orders my bibliography in the order in which articles were cited. Occasionally, however, I want an `\cite` to be ignored for the purposes of the bibliography order, but fully working otherwise.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{c} % Want to cite, but ignore for purpose of bibliography order.
\cite{a}
\cite{b}
\cite{c}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ex}
\end{document}
```

with ex.bib:

```
@article{a, author="a"}
@article{b, author="b"}
@article{c, author="c"}
```

results in:

[image]

as expected. I want to replace that first citation with a new command, say `\ignorecite` so that the order is `a,b,c`, and so that the order in the main document is `3,1,2,3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the capability to write a citation to the `.aux` file. This is achieved by momentarily setting `\@fileswfalse`:

```
\newcommand{\ignorecite}[1]{{\@fileswfalse\cite{#1}}}%
```

With the entire `\cite` command still in tact, hyperlinks and formatting functions as usual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Write bibliography items to file
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{ex.bib}
@article{a, author="a"}
@article{b, author="b"}
@article{c, author="c"}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ignorecite}[1]{{\@fileswfalse\cite{#1}}}%
\makeatother
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort]{natbib}% http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\ignorecite{c} % Want to cite, but ignore for purpose of bibliography order.
\cite{a}
\cite{b}
\cite{c}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. Smart solution.

Comment: Is there a similar solution when using biblatex?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Werner's answer, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44753/105075) by Frank Mittelbach proposes a command that takes the citation call itself:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ignorecitefornumbering#1{%
     \begingroup
         \@fileswfalse
         #1%                     % do \cite comand
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```