# How to tell bibtex to ignore the citations in the abstract when numbering the references?

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran, ieee-style

I use the [IEEEtran](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en) bibliography style for my article. By default, the first-cited reference cited in the document is numbered as [1], the second one as [2], and so on.

This seems to be IEEE's standard. However, there is a problem when I cite something in the abstract. Since the document starts with the abstract, that particular reference is numbered as [1] while it is the tenth reference cited in the *text*. I want to avoid this. That is, to start numbering the references in the order they appear in the main text, *ignoring the abstract* and then putting the corresponding number in the abstract (in my example, the reference in the abstract should appear as [10] rather than [1]).

I found a trick to do so, which is to first comment out the citation in the abstract, run the bibtex (so that it doesn't see it there and number it according to where it appears in the text), and then put it back. This works fine but I should always be careful to do these steps before rerunning the bibtex (e.g. when I add a reference, ...).

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically tell bibtex to ignore the abstract for the numbering?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article1,
    author = {Author 1},
    title  = {Title 1},
    year   = 1993,
    month  = may,
    pages  = {10--15}
  }

  @inproceedings{article2,
    author = {Author 2},
    booktitle  = {Conference Title},
    title  = {Article 2},
    year   = 1975,
    month  = aug,
    pages  = {120--125}
  }

  @book{book1,
    author = {Autor 3},
    title = {Book Title},
    publishe = {Publisher},
    year = 2005
  }
}
\end{filecontents}




\usepackage{cite}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
% make the title area
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  This article \cite{article2} is numbered as [1] while I would like it to be
  numbered (and referenced to) as [2].
\end{abstract}

In fact, \cite{article1} is the one that I want to be numbered as [1], then
\cite{article2} as [2] and finally \cite{book1} as [3] as they appear in this
order in the article body. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is perhaps a way. But it is very difficult to find and test it without code. So make a minimal example.

Comment: How to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I prepared a MWE and appended it to the question.

Comment: As a related problem, this answer may be helpfull: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132509

Comment: Also, this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44753/105075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible trick is to wrap the citation in the abstract in a `\IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{}` test, and use the following workflow

```
rm <filename>.bbl 
pdflatex <filename>  
bibtex <filename> 
pdflatex <filename> 
pdflatex <filename>
```

You can use `array` to specify the workflow.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article1,
    author = {Author 1},
    title  = {Title 1},
    year   = 1993,
    month  = may,
    pages  = {10--15}
  }

  @inproceedings{article2,
    author = {Author 2},
    booktitle  = {Conference Title},
    title  = {Article 2},
    year   = 1975,
    month  = aug,
    pages  = {120--125}
  }

  @book{book1,
    author = {Autor 3},
    title = {Book Title},
    publishe = {Publisher},
    year = 2005
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}
\title{MWE}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  This article \IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{\cite{article2}}{*} is
  numbered as [1] while I would like it to be numbered (and 
  referenced to) as [2].
\end{abstract}

In fact, \cite{article1} is the one that I want to be numbered as [1], then
\cite{article2} as [2] and finally \cite{book1} as [3] as they appear in this
order in the article body. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

After the first run you get:

[image]

After running `bibtex` and the second `pdflatex` run you have

[image]

and finally:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should insert the instruction `\nocite{article1}` *before* the `abstract` environment. That way, it'll be numbered as `[1]` even though no citation call-out is generated by the `\nocite` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article1,
    author = {Author 1},
    title  = {Title 1},
    year   = 1993,
    month  = may,
    pages  = {10--15}
  }

  @inproceedings{article2,
    author = {Author 2},
    booktitle  = {Conference Title},
    title  = {Article 2},
    year   = 1975,
    month  = aug,
    pages  = {120--125}
  }

  @book{book1,
    author = {Autor 3},
    title = {Book Title},
    publishe = {Publisher},
    year = 2005
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}

%\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
% make the title area
\maketitle
\nocite{article1}  % dummy reference to "article1"
\begin{abstract}
This article \cite{article2} is numbered as [2], which is exactly what I want.
\end{abstract}

Happily, \cite{article1} is now numbered as~[1], then \cite{article2} as~[2], and finally \cite{book1} as~[3]. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico, but I imagine if the problematic reference is for example the tenth one being cited in the text, I should put 9 \nocites (for everything else which is being cited before the one being cited in the article). This is not very efficient. Is there a more automated way to do this?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi - The `\cite` and `\nocite` macros, as modified by the `cite` package, which you load, can take multiple arguments. Thus, you could issue a single `\nocite` directive, with nine arguments. OK, that's still not exactly straightforward. A separate thought: How essential is it to have an explicit numeric citation call-out in the document's abstract? Would the abstract be any less readable if no citation call-out was provided? If readability/intelligibility is not adversely affected by this omission, I'd remove the citation call-out from the abstract.

Comment: Well, as you mentioned, no matter if one uses nine `\nocite` commands or a single one with nine arguments it is still an inefficient solution (I'd prefer my own stupid solution to comment out the `\cite` part of the abstract, run `pdflatex` and then `bibtex` and then put back the `\cite` in the abstract and run `pdflatex` again). 

As for your second question, I almost agree with you that it is usually better not to cite anything in the abstract and have been try to avoid doing this in practice. However, sometimes one has to do this.